# Rails exceptions - get instance variables from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, sentry

We're using raven-sentry in our application and I would like to have a default 'catch all' set of extra options applied to all errors.

```
class StandardError
  def raven_context
    extra = {}

    #add conditional key/values to the hash if they exist
    extra[:account_id] = @account.id if @account

    extra.empty? ? {} : { extra: extra }
  end
end
```

Because the exception is raising from an instantiated class in either a model or controller, I thought I'd be able to access those variables.  If accounts#show raised an exception, I'd want to be able to access @account.  If Account.create() raised an exception, I'd like to be able to get some information about that account, like errors.

Is this possible? and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [Rails idea](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b326e82dc012d81e9698cb1f402502af1788c1e9/activerecord/lib/active_record/errors.rb) of how to catch/raise the exception such as `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`

So basically you can design a generic error like:

```
class MyGenericError < StandardError
  attr_reader :account, :others

  def initialize(message = nil, account = nil, others={})
    @account = account
    @others  = others
    super(message)
  end
end

class MySpecificError < MyGenericError; end
```

So now when you raise an error, just pass the necessary params like:

```
raise MySpecificError.new('doing something wrong', @account) if doing_something_wrong
```

Finally, when catching the error, you just get the `account` attribute and freely use it

Comment: The only problem here is it'll be errors I specifically raise.  With Sentry I can pass all the information through Raven.capture_exception(e, extra: {whatever I want}).  Sentry also captures unhandled exceptions, these are the one's I'm particularly interested in.